# Options for mapping EF 1 to 0..1 relationship across multiple tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to model the following relationships via EF poco:

```
Class TableA
{
  [Key]
  public int TableAId {get;set;}

  public Attribute Attribute {get;set;}
}

Class TableB
{
  [Key]
  public int TableBId {get;set;}

  public Attribute Attribute {get;set;}
}

Class Attribute
{
  [Key]
  public int AttributeId {get;set;}

  public string Name{get; set}
}
```

where TableA and TableB both reference Attribute.

To do so I inserted the following fluent mappings:

```
 new EntityTypeConfiguration<TableA>().HasRequired(x => x.Attribute);
 new EntityTypeConfiguration<TableB>().HasRequired(x => x.Attribute);
```

all is fine and I can add elements using this type of approach:

```
 var a = new TableA();
 var attrA = new Attribute { Name = "Table A Attribute"};
 a.Attribute = attrA;

 MyDbContext.TableAs.Add(a);
 MyDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

until I want to delete both TableA (or B) and the referenced Attribute.

```
 MyDBContex.TableAs.Remove(a);
 MyDBContex.Attributes.Remove(a.Attribute);
```

which causes an exception that complains about FKs.

What options do I have to map and configure such relationships?

I need to insert and remove TableA and TableB objects and cascade delete their related Attribute entries.

Answer (score 1):

If you want cascading delete in a one-to-one relationship you must configure it explicitly, it is not enabled by default:

```
new EntityTypeConfiguration<TableA>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.Attribute)
    .WithOptional()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

(And the same for `TableB`.)

One-to-one relationships with EF are always shared primary key associations which means that the foreign key is the primary key at the same time. The consequence is that with enabled cascading delete removal of the principal `a.Attribute`...

```
MyDBContex.Attributes.Remove(a.Attribute);
```

...will also delete a related `TableB` record that has the same primary key value as `a` and `a.Attribute` (if there is any). You can't avoid that without violating a foreign key constraint.